# How to change the classloader jar location in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, websphere, classpath, classloader

Good day,

I have a web application that deploy in WebSphere through WAS Console.

I go to left side navigation, click on `Troubleshooting --> Class loader viewer`, and then click on my server to enter the class loader viewer detail. The following image show part of my class loader jars.
[image]

I would like to change those jars to point to another location jars. For example, from 
`/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java_1.7.1_64/jre/lib/ext/CmpCrmf.jar`

change to
`/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ext/CmpCrmf.jar`

I tried to google about this but mostly is talking about the parent load first or child load first. So I am not sure where should I go to configure for this.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Extension Class Loader's class path is driven by the java.ext.dirs system property passed into the JVM (by default on WAS, it's the tivoli/tam and JAVA_HOME/lib/ext directories). Rather than attempting to change the value of this property, you'd be better served by changing the version of Java your server is configured to use - trying to use libraries from two separate Java versions would be extremely difficult to manage.

To switch Java versions, you'll want to use the managesdk.sh/bat script, which allows you to manage Java SDKs available to your server. If you want the one in AppServer/java, switch your profile to use that version instead of the one in AppServer/java-1.7.1_64. Documentation on the script can be found at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/rxml_managesdk.html (the link implies IBM i, but the documentation does not appear to be platform-specific).